# Synchronize codes and applications between windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, synchronization

There are 10+ windows 2008 server(s) in front of which we use the F5 as the loader.

Now we meet some problems during the deploying of the application, these application are served by IIS.

Each server may contains more than one application(s), and the application may be updated frequently which menas we need to upload the latest application source codes to each server.

Also we may need to create new IIS websites or application, update the configuration sometimes which need to be synchronized too.

It would be tried or make error if all of the job are done manually.

We have thought the file(folder) sync tools, however it does not support dynamical operation like `Creating Application` or `Updating configuration`.

So I wonder if there is any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

For data sync only, one possibility is to use FreeFileSync to keep the Windows machines synchronized: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeFileSync

However, the real solutions is probably to use some kind of shared storage (eg: via SMB/CIFS) and deploy application using its sharing capabilities.

For sharing configuration, I think the best option is to configure a cluster with shared settings, but I am not a Windows Clustering expert...